# Taking Raw data from txt file and putting it into columns in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, excel

Simply put: I have a text file with values in separate lines and some on the same line:

```
value 1: xxxx
Value 2: xxxx
Value 3: xxxx  Value 4: xxxx Value 5: xxxx
```

I have a database with all the columns as the values. I am not sure how to insert the data into the DB using SQL since I can not modify the text file only upload it into the script.  Is there any way to pull the data out and plot it into the columns?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, it involves some manual steps.

### First, we need to get the data into the rows only.

1. Go to Excel > Data > Get external data > From Text
2. Select a txt file with raw data.
3. Choose Delimited, with space, treat consecutive delimiters as one. See picture.
4. Select the 4th through 6th columns.
5. Go To Special > Constants > OK.
6. Copy the selected cells. Cut will not work.
7. Go to the bottom of the first 3 columns and paste. See picture.
8. Repeat steps 4~7 for the next group of 3 columns.

**Text import wizard**

[image]

**After import**

[image]

**Select columns and Go To Special, constants.**

[image]

**Copy and paste to the bottom of columns 1~3**

[image]

### Second, we can simply filter the column headings and copy values below each other.

1. Concatenate the Text and Number part of the column name, so that you only have 2 columns. Like `Value 2:` and `xxxxx`.
2. Create a top heading we will use for filtering. Add a filter. See picture.
3. Filter or sort all the column names one by one and copy the values in columns. See picture.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: @user3688183, I have added a second part of the answer. May it be of help.